# Scaling a bitmap using Bicubic or Bilinear scaling

Tags: java, android, kotlin, bitmap

Upon uploading an image through my android app, I downscale it to a size of 360px wide. However, I think the downscaling is horrendously bad with jagged edges and a pixelated look. When I downscale the same image in photoshop using the Bicubic or Bilinear scaling options, the photo looks lovely and surprisingly sharp for such a small image.
How can i scale a bitmap in an android application using one of these scaling methods? I suspect the one that's being used right now is Nearest Neighbour.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Unbl.jpg

The code I'm using to scale bitmaps now is:

```
val resizedBitmapSmall =
            Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(sourceBitmap, targetWidthSmall, targetHeightSmall, true)
```

Thanks!

Comment: Actually according to documentation nearest-neighbor is used when creating scaled bitmap is called with `false`. So the method used is bilinear filtering. See here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap#createScaledBitmap(android.graphics.Bitmap,%20int,%20int,%20boolean)

Comment: I think it isn't much you can do with the Android APIs and custom downscaling should be implemented.